# Adding Google Drive Files as Attachments to Previously Created Draft in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail, gmail-api, email-attachments

I am currently working on an Apps Script project where I need to add two Google Drive files as attachments to an existing Gmail draft without modifying other parts of the draft, such as its subject or body. However, the current implementation that retrieves the draft, updates its content, and adds the attachments seems to cause a disruption in the draft's structure, even resulting in a change of the draft's ID.

I would like to know if there is a more efficient and reliable method to add these Google Drive files to the draft without altering its existing content or affecting the draft's ID. Ideally, I want to preserve the structure of the draft and solely append the new attachments to the existing ones.

Here is a snippet of the code I am currently using:

```
var fileId1 = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var fileId2 = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

// Retrieve the existing draft
var draft = GmailApp.getDraft(draftId);
var recipient = draft.getMessage().getTo();
var subject = draft.getMessage().getSubject();
var body = draft.getMessage().getBody();

// Get the existing attachments of the draft
var existingAttachments = draft.getMessage().getAttachments();

// Attach the first file to the email
var file1 = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId1);
var attachmentBlob1 = file1.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

// Attach the second file to the email
var file2 = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId2);
var attachmentBlob2 = file2.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

// Combine existing attachments with new attachments
var allAttachments = existingAttachments.concat(attachmentBlob1, attachmentBlob2);

// Update the draft with recipient, subject, body, and attachments
draft.update(recipient, subject, body, {
  attachments: allAttachments
});
```

I appreciate any insights or alternative methods that will help me achieve the desired functionality while maintaining the draft's structure and integrity. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating `seems to cause a disruption in the draft's structure, even resulting in a change of the draft's ID`?

Comment: @Tanaike In fact, my provided code is just an initial sample that I coded but it is not working properly and creates another draft and then copy the content of the previous draft to a new draft with a new draft ID. I simply want to add those two files from google drive to the current draft without creating a new draft. It is not necessary to modify the above code. it is just a suggestion. Can you provide your own code and solution for this issue?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `creates another draft and then copy the content of the previous draft to a new draft with a new draft ID`. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly replicate it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: @Tanaike I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me another proper solution for addressing this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to create the draft from scratch using Gmail.app in app script using create draft code. It works fine!
this is the code snippet:

```
  var attachments = [];


    var file = DriveApp.getFileById("Your attachment file id");
    attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF));

  // Create the draft with attachments
  var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(
    "Your email address", 
    "Your subject", 
    "Your email body", 
    {
      attachments: attachments,
    }
```